# Can't render latex in matplotlib.pyplot in python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pdflatex

While something like `matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel(r'Wavelenghth [$\mu$m]')` works in  python2 I get error when I use it in python 3

> TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not
>   bytes

Does anyone know what it the problem? Is it from my latex installation?!

Comment: Could you please show the whole error traceback in your question, not just the last line.

Comment: This works just fine for me in Python 3, using your exact line above. As per the previous comment - could you show the whole traceback?  Are you sure it is this line that gives the error?  The error given doesn't seem to match that string.

Comment: Thank you... And sorry that I reply late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could  solve the problem using rc('text', usetex=False) which apparently make the matplotlib to use the internal mathtext instead of my default  latex installation.

Still I can not figure out the reason why my OS latex installation fails.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a minimal working example? And if so, post that example here, with backtrace of the error if possible? As others have mentioned as well, it's a bit difficult to determine what is going wrong now, the code snippet that you posted looks okay..